# Error on CodeDeploy only solved after reboot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I have a weird problem where my CodeDeploy suddenly stops working giving me this error:

```
[stderr]An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeAutoScalingInstances operation: User: arn:aws:iam::552419262942:user/instanceICGS3 is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances
```

That user has CodeDeploy Full access, and S3 Full Access, and even setting Administrator Full, I keep getting the same error.

But the weird thing is that when I restart the instance, CodeDeploy starts working as usual with just the CodeDeploy Full access, and S3 Full Access I had before.

What am I missing?